# MySql and Laravel: Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '1' for key

Tags: mysql

Can anyone explain to me where I made a mistake and how to fix this error? I've tried several ways that are suggested on the stackoverflow site, but it still doesn't work.

Am using Laravel 8 and MySql 8.0.25 version.

This table contains information about customer addresses. The customer can have multiple addresses but only one primary one. The primary address is in the "primarna" column and is set to be unique. I also set up a unique "subjekti_id" (en: customer_id) column. The other columns are foreign keys that point to the country, city, and post ID.
It should be noted that I have only on one foreign key defined `onDelete('CASCADE')` function for the reason that when the customer is deleted I want all addresses from this customer to be deleted from this table. All other foreign keys for country, city and post `onUpdate` and `onDelete` is set to `SET NULL`.

**This is ERROR:**

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
> '1' for key 'subjekat_adrese_subjekti_id_unique' (SQL: insert into
> `subjekat_adrese` (`naziv`, `adresa`, `subjekti_id`, `drzave_id`,
> `gradovi_id`, `poste_id`, `primarna`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
> values (Test name, Test address, 1, 2, 5, 2, ?, 2022-06-07 06:46:17,
> 2022-06-07 06:46:17))

**Databas Schema:**

[image: Screenshot database schema]

**Database records**

Only one record have.

```
id | naziv |   Adresa     | subjekat_id | drzave_id| gradovi_id | poste_id | primarna 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'1','Test',' Test address'      '1',         '2',       '5',        '2',     '1',
```

**Indexes & Foreign keys**
Only one key is set onDlete cascade. All other is SET NULL.

[image: Indexes]
[image: Foreign keys]

**What i try:**

```
insert into `subjekat_adrese` (`naziv`, `adresa`, `subjekti_id`, `drzave_id`, `gradovi_id`, `poste_id`, `primarna`)
 values ('Test name', 'Test address', '1', '2', '5', '2', null');
```

This return:

```
 Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '1' for key 'subjekat_adrese_subjekti_id_unique'
```

If i try to insert non existing unique ('subjekat_id')

```
insert into `subjekat_adrese` (`naziv`, `adresa`, `subjekti_id`, `drzave_id`, `gradovi_id`, `poste_id`, `primarna`)
     values ('Bla bla', 'bla bla', '2', '3', '3', '3', null');
```

This return this:

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`laravel`.`subjekat_adrese`, CONSTRAINT `subjekat_adrese_subjekti_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`subjekti_id`) REFERENCES `subjekti` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE SET NULL)
```

**UPDATE (ADD MIGRATION)**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('subjekat_adrese', function (Blueprint $table) {
           
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
           
            $table->string('naziv')->default("N/O");
            $table->string('adresa');

            $table->boolean('primarna')->unique()->nullable()->default(NULL);

            $table->timestamps();

            
        });

        Schema::table('subjekat_adrese', function($table) {

            $table->foreignId('subjekti_id')
                ->unique()
                ->nullable()
                ->constrained('subjekti')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('set null');

            $table->foreignId('drzave_id')
                ->nullable()
                ->constrained('drzave')
                ->onDelete('set null')
                ->onUpdate('set null');

            $table->foreignId('gradovi_id')
                ->nullable()
                ->constrained('gradovi')
                ->onDelete('set null')
                ->onUpdate('set null');

            $table->foreignId('poste_id')
                ->nullable()
                ->constrained('poste')
                ->onDelete('set null')
                ->onUpdate('set null');
        });
    }
```

**Update 2**
Screenshot of the `subjekti` table records.

[image: Subjekti table]

Comment: What does your migration look like? Seems like the primary key column is not auto incremented.

Comment: sorry. I can't see the issue here. 
first error: you already inserting a value you already have in the table. that should throw exception sense you're having a unique constraint on the column. 

second error: you don't have the id in `subjekti` table, that is why you see the foreign key error.

or do I miss something 
please let me know

Comment: @geertjanknapen check for update. I add migration code now

Comment: @omaresmaeel i not post `subjekti` table but in that table i have `id` with auto increment and only one record `id  = 1`. In this table i have only one record when i try to insert new record autoincrement not work properly and when i change unique get second error.

Comment: @omaresmaeel check for update

Comment: @Ivan Why not use Eloquent relationships for this? Also subjekti_id should not be unique since it's a foreign key.

Comment: Am using Eloquent.  I need `subjekti_id` to be unique.

Comment: You wrote, " The primary address is in the "primarna" column and is set to be unique."  SQL constraints don't work that way. You can't use UNIQUE constraints to make some rows of a table unique and others not unique.

Answer (score 1):

the reason of the first error
 `Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '1' for key 'subjekat_adrese_subjekti_id_unique'`

is the making of `subjekti_id` as unique , this field should'nt be unique here as it's a foreign key and it may be attached to multiple rows.

and about why the second error appears `Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '1' for key 'subjekat_adrese_subjekti_id_unique'`

is that there is no row at subjekti with id `2`

Comment: If you would delete the unique key from `subjekti_id` then only one primary address would be primary for all customers. For a unique customer address, I must have a unique `subjekti_id` and a column `primarna` that containing the value for the primary address. 1 for true null for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your foreign key can not be unique alone. For your scenario you should make unique subjekti_id + primarna together.

```
$table->unique(['subjekti_id', 'primarna']);
```